# Using peakutils - Detecting 'dull' peaks

Tags: python, peakutils

I'm currently using peakutils to find peaks in some data. My data contains some "dull peaks", that is my peaks plateau somewhat. I can't set my code to find these peaks even after playing around with the threshold and minimum distance parameters. The graph has the same maximum for 2 straight data points, and then fall back down. Yet they are still not considered peaks. Any help would be appreciated.

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm50p.png)

My code is essentially the same as in this [example](https://plot.ly/python/peak-fitting/).

Comment: Please see [mcve]. If you can include the actual code you're using, it will help folks be able to pinpoint _your_ problem. The link you've provided will take readers more than a reasonable amount of time to track down what it is you're trying to say, and may not help them answer your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

In working with the repo owner on this same problem I discovered that the module was not up to date. I made the mistake as a beginner to python of assuming that imports were always the most recent version, a simple version update resolved this issue as the module has included this feature in version 1.1.0. I had to ask my own question for this, days ago, as I could not comment on your question due to low rep.

What I did, in terminal, is run `pip freeze` to find my current version and then `sudo pip install peakutils --upgrade` to update it.